# Bluetooth scheduler

Tags: bluetooth

I want to automatically turn bluetooth on and off during day, for example set bluetooth to be on only between 8 a.m. and 10 a.m.

Is there any application that will allow me to do it? Or does API allow to turn bluetooth on/off from applications at all (including any workarounds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *implied* in the [video announcing Windows Phone 8.1](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2014/04/02/cortana-yes-and-many-many-other-great-features-coming-in-windows-phone-8-1.aspx) that Cortana, the upcoming digital assistant that can set settings for you, and also the schedule "stuff".

I'm joining the dots a bit, and until it's all released for general availability, there is scope for details to change, but it certainly looks like you could do something like turning Bluetooth on and off as required.

Comment: Currently, there are no api's to turn on and off these features. There is a way for a program to send you to the settings page to change it, although this would be highly annoying. Toggling the Bluetooth will be available from the new action center and would be an easy way to turn it on and off as needed.